# WP7 - Animation ends too early and no effect remains

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation, code-behind

I made an animation to rotate my control, but when it's trigert it just jumps to final position and then immediately returns to starting position.

The Controls are made from code behind and are TextBoxes with following properties:

```
FontSize = 45;
TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
Widh = 40;
Heigh = 45;
```

I store the TextBoxes in array, so I trigger the animation with following code:

```
foreach (TextBlock b in arrayOfTextBoxes)
{
    Rotate(b);
}
```

Animation:

```
public static void Rotate(UIElement target)
{
        var projection = new PlaneProjection();
        target.Projection = projection;

        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 0;
        da.To = 90;
        da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25);
        da.AutoReverse = false;

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationZProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, projection);

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(da);

        EventHandler eh = null;
        eh = (s, args) =>
        {
            projection.RotationZ = 90;
            sb.Stop();
            sb.Completed -= eh;
        };
        sb.Completed += eh;

        sb.Begin();
}
```

<strike>**EDIT**: Now i propably know what's the problem. I have one (sometimes two) Dispatcher Times ticking in background every second. When I disable them, the proble's gone. But I can't do it because I need them to measure time. 
Stoping them just before I trigger the animation and them starting them again does'n help.
//The DispetcherTimers do this:</strike>

```
        void tikac_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        herniCas += new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }
```

Comment: I have no answer to your question, just a suggestion: you don't have to create a `EventHandler eh` var, you can just use an anonymous delegate instead.

Comment: @jv42: The pattern of using an `eh` variable is generally a good one, since it allows the delegate to removed from the event once it has been executed.

Comment: Just making sure, you intend for the duration of the animation to be a  quarter of a second, IE very fast.  The jump to final position isn't just because its animating very fast then executing your storyboard completed event?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones doh, I read too quickly and skipped over the removal part, thanks for pointing it out! It is indeed very useful.

Comment: Actually it was also an emulator problem. In real devise everything worked much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation storyboards will normally hold the last value "until they are stopped". They do not permanently change the actual property value. They just change its currently rendered value (aren't dependency properties wonderful? :))

As you are explicitly stopping it when it ends the value reverts to its original value. Do not stop the storyboard if you want the value to stay changed, or explicitly set it in code when the animation changes.

The animation in your example is so fast it is just ending very quickly (startup time for storyboards can be a few frames and any time in between is skipped as animations are fixed-time interpolations, not frame specific).